# Why isn't "position:fixed;" keeping my page header in the same place?

Tags: html, css, css-position, fixed

I'm trying to expand a menu when someone clicks on the menu icon but right now when I do that its pushing over the page title -- [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wtp1k57b/8/).  I would like the page title to stay in the same place during the menu opening/closing interaction.  The HTML5 I'm using to construct the page title and the menu are

```css
#pageTitle {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
}

ul.horizontal {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li.menuItem {
  float: left;
}

li.menuItem a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="pageTitle">
  <h2>Page Title</h2>

  <details class="mobile-nav">
    <summary class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
      <div></div>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </summary>

    <div class="responsive-menu">
      <ul id="menu">
        <li>Vote</li>
        <li>Search</li>
        <li>About</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </details>
</div>
```

I thought using `position: fixed;` would keep the page title where it was but it keeps getting pushed over.
How can I keep it from getting pushed over while allowing the menu opening/closing to happen?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use position:fixed in addition to `left:0, right:0 and top:0`. See below:

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange; 
  text-align: center;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
}
```

Basically `left:0, right:0` make the header take up the full viewport width, and `top:0` positions it at the top of the page.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/wtp1k57b/9/)

Comment: I'm not seeing your Fiddle working -- at least not on Mac Firefox.  When I click on the menu it is shifting the page title header far over to the left.  Here's what I see -- https://imgur.com/a/LadDw .

Comment: Ok and where would you like it? Underneath the title?

Comment: if so, change your expand class like so : .expand {
        display: block !important;
        position:absolute;
        right:0;
}

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response Jonathan.  I applied the styling you suggested -- https://jsfiddle.net/wtp1k57b/11/ and now the "Page title" header stays fixed when I click on my icon, which is good, but now the menu doesn't appear at all underneath the icon.